# Is it possible to restore previously open frames in emacs after full screening (ESC) one of them?

Tags: emacs

I am using emacs and usually have multiple buffers open using horizontal and vertical splits. Sometimes I need to view one of the buffers in full screen and press ESC for that. However is it possible to restore the previous screen placement ? ie if I had 4 frames open, then can I restore them back ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/WinnerMode

^ is the best

C-c left to restore previous window placement

Answer (score 1):

You can use `window-configuration-to-register` or `frame-configuration-to-register` to save the window and frame configurations to a register and restore them. You can use this along with a little elisp to give you the functionality you need.

I have some more details about how to use registers posted in [this screencast](http://emacsmovies.org/blog/2012/07/08/registers_and_bookmarks/).